# IntelliJ code completion in HTML files overly aggressive with certain tags

Tags: intellij-idea

The code completion in IntelliJ is generally quite good.
However, when working with HTML documents, the code completion on certain HTML tags is very agressive.

By this I mean, if I'm typing some text within a `<p>` tag for instance, let's say the text is: "This is **a** annoying feature". As soon as I hit the space bar after the letter 'a', IntelliJ expands that to: `<a href=""></a>`. This makes me want to tear my hair out after a while...

Anyone know how/where to disable that or configure it? (Noticed it on IntelliJ 12 & 13)

Comment: It doesn't do that to me. It does offer a list of things I could choose, if I were to hit enter, but it doesn't actually do the substitution unless I ask it to -- it just allows me to type. What options do you have selected in the editor/code-completion settings?

Comment: @EngineerDollery In my case, what you describe is true when editing say, a .java source file. However, for HTML files it just completes immediately after hitting space. I have tried disabling all code completion options, including `Auto-insert when only one choice on: ... `, which sounded promising but does not help. See here: http://goo.gl/pvU2TG.

Comment: I tried it in both jsp and html files and I don't get the same behaviour, which implies that it must be a problem with one of the settings. Have you raised the issue with Jetbrains? They're very good at helping out with odd problems. Also, the link you provided seems to be to a broken image -- you can paste images in your question if you think it'll help clarify things.

Comment: Hmm, apparently you need to Sign In with a Google account to view the image. I'll raise with JetBrains. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the help of JetBrains support, disabling the following Live Template fixed it:

[image]

Comment: This happens because the live template expand key is set to `Space` instead of `Tab`.